# How can I add a where into my foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
foreach ( var menuItem in  Model.menuItems) {
  if (menuItem.Type == "02") {

  }
}
```

The code within the foreach executes only when Type==2 so is there some way that I could add the check for Type == "02" into the top part of my loop.

Comment: I think maybe you could pull out the relevant ones by `Model.menuItems.Where(item => item.Type == "02")` and then do the processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your menuItems already are enumerable:

```
foreach (var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(c => c.Type == "02")) { 
}
```

Otherwise try:

```
foreach (var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Type == "02")) { 
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.ToList().Where(c => c.Type == "02")) { 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[**`List(Of T).ForEach Method`**  :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) Performs the specified action on each element of the `List(Of T)`.

```
Model.menuItems.Where(c => c.Type == "02").ToList().ForEach(delegate(type data)
        {
            //code to execute

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach ( var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(mi => mi.Type == "02") {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ:

```
foreach (var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(item => item.Type == "02")) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with linq using the following:

```
foreach ( var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(m=>m.Type == "02") {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

do

```
foreach ( var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(m => m.Type == "02")) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
foreach ( var menuItem in  Model.menuItems.Where(m => m.Type == "02")) {

}
```